# Laravel, PHP, and OPCache - Not caching all files

Tags: php, laravel, opcache

My Laravel application has roughly 10,000 files, including the 3rd party packages in my vendor directory.  However, with OPCache enabled, it seems to only be caching 667 files and 1,321 keys.

Is there anything I'm missing, or is that potentially accurate?  Below are some of the stats from my OPCache Status:

`total memory: 300.00MB
used memory: 26.83MB
free memory: 273.17MB
wasted memory: 0.00b (0%)
number of cached files: 667
number of hits: 3,621,095
number of misses: 849
blacklist misses: 0
number of cached keys: 1,321
max cached keys: 16,229`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski max_accelerated_files is set to 10,000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `artisan optimize`, it compiles PHP classes into single `compiled.php`.

Also, not all files are php, and not all php files are being used.

I'd expect static files to be served directly by httpd without using php, and tests should not to be touched on prod at all.

Comment: thats seems pretty accurate.  While the 10,000 files are in fact all PHP files, you're right that much of it is being put into the compiled files via artisan optimize.  thanks!